# Django: how can I apply a middleware action only to certain filetypes?

Tags: python, django, http

I'm working in Django, and I want to apply some middleware ONLY to HTML pages - not to images, js, css etc. This is to reduce the number of requests on the server.

This is my middleware code:

```
class checkLdapUser:
    def process_request(self, request):
        if response.META['CONTENT_TYPE'] is 'text/html':
            # check the LDAP user here
        else:
            return None
```

How can I check the `CONTENT_TYPE`?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

working code:

```
def process_response(self, request, response):
    if response.get('Content-Type', '')=='text/html':
        # do stuff
    return response
```

Comment: Django does not serve images, JS or CSS in any case. If you're making it serve those files in production, you're doing it horribly wrong.

Comment: Sorry, this is on the development server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you need to put that code in `process_response` rather than `process_request`. The latter runs before the request is handled by your view code, so it doesn't have access to the response and its content type.